# Can we do CRUD operations on SQL Server .MDF file without Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server `.mdf` file and I want to do insert, delete, update queries on that without using SQL Server Management Studio.

Because it is located is remote system and I want to give some updated as add column to table and delete data

Comment: Yes - all you need to access the `.mdf` database file is an installation of the **SQL Server database engine** - the GUI tool Management Studio isn't needed - you can run your command with  `sqlcmd` on the command line, or you can write a program to do this, or you can use any number of other GUI tools to deal with a SQL Server database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can manage your DB using `sqlcmd` utility - for extensive documentation on this you can read the following documentation. [SQLCMD Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility)